# Wordpress Content Blocks Missing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Content blocks are missing in Wordpress when editing a post.

Based on the screenshots below, why is 'hide-if'js' being added to the 'postbox' class for specific IDs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** The blocks that are missing are displayed in the screenshots to show what IS missing/should be displayed when editing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Content blocks" - what do you mean? Are you talking about the meta boxes that appear in WordPress "edit post"? If so, did you click the "Screen Options" tab in the top-right corner, and ensure the meta box(es) you want to use have the checkbox checked? The `hide-if-js` is core WP behavior, part of their functionality to allow you to hide / display things easily *if javascript is enabled*

Comment: I honestly had no idea that the "Screen Options" tab was there. You solved my problem. Thank you for taking the time.